# How to avoid _0 _1 when editing a media entity and changing the file?

Tags: media

Say I add an image using the built-in Media module.

A couple months later, I have to change the image file for some reason.  So I edit the media entity, delete the existing file, and upload the new file.  The new file has the same name as the old file.

This creates a new file, **filename_0.jpg**.  How can I cleanly replace the file without adding a new suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Media Entity File Replace](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_file_replace) module.  This is the exact use case it was created for.